# Select Sum from Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the sum hours for each month from a given user and having problems with the code. Need help.

what I have so far:

> $sql = "SELECT sum(hours) AS total_Hours FROM flights WHERE month = 3
>   and username='$myname'";

This isn't even working, But what i really need is total hours from user for each month.
possible?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query asking sum for each month:

```
SELECT SUM(`hours`) AS total_Hours, `month` FROM flights 
WHERE `username`='some_user'
GROUP BY `month`
```

Also you should know that your `$myname` variable must to be escaped with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before passing in a query.

@Robbie is telling right about escaping `month`. It seems to be the only problem of your query.

Comment: Month is a reserved word - put it in quotes or this won't work either.

Comment: You're almost right but MySQL use another character for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT user, month, SUM(hours) AS total_hours
FROM flights
GROUP BY user, month
ORDER BY user, month
```

Comment: Month is a reserved word - put it in quotes or this won't work either

Comment: It's not a reserved word. There's a MONTH() function, but this is not a function call. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html